# Phalcon 4 data strange symbol during getJsonRawBody

Tags: phalcon

I'm using [Phalcon 4](http://phalcon.io) and I send a POST in JSON format to Phalcon controller.

The JSON is:

```
birthday    "12/12/2020"
country "ddf"
id  "15bbde30-3714-11ec-95e7-8163123e4768"
name    "df"
```

but when I analyze it:

```
public function post(): ResponseInterface
    {
        $this->view->disable();

     
        $body =  $this->request->getJsonRawBody();
        return $this->response->setStatusCode(502)->setContent(json_encode(($body-> birthday)));
```

the result is:

```
"12\/12\/2020"
```

I'm not able to understand why Phalcon add this strange symbol `\/`

If I do another test like it (I have removed `-> birthday`):

```
public function post(): ResponseInterface
    {
        $this->view->disable();

     
        $body =  $this->request->getJsonRawBody();
        return $this->response->setStatusCode(502)->setContent(json_encode(($body)));
```

I have the excepted result:

```
birthday    "12/12/2020"
country "ddf"
id  "15bbde30-3714-11ec-95e7-8163123e4768"
name    "df"
```

Have you a solution in order to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

your issue is not with Phalcon its with php's `json_encode()`

if you don't want the slashes to be escaped just add the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` flag

```php
return $this->response
    ->setStatusCode(502)
    ->setContent(json_encode($body, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
```

check the php's documentation on json_encode() [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)